Unable to successfully deploy a Flask app to Kubernetes (`net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`)
I am trying to make make a calculator where each operation is a microservice. I'm trying to deploy the first, divide service to Kubernetes.
Here's the code:
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from flask_cors import CORS

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)

@app.route('/divide', methods=['GET'])
def divide():
    num1 = float(request.args.get('num1'))
    num2 = float(request.args.get('num2'))
    if num2 == 0:
        return jsonify({'error': 'Cannot divide by zero'})
    result = num1 / num2
    return jsonify({'result': result})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=5004)


Dockerfile
# Use an official Python runtime as a base image
FROM python:3.9-slim

# Set the working directory in the container
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the current directory contents into the container at /app
COPY . /app

# Install Flask and Flask-CORS directly (if they are not already installed in the base image)
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir flask flask-cors

# Make port 5004 available to the world outside this container
EXPOSE 5004

# Run app.py when the container launches
CMD ["python", "divide_service.py"]

Deployment:
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: divide-service-py
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: divide-service-py
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: divide-service-py
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: divide-service-py
        image: katzir/divide-py:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5004

Service:
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: divide-service-py
spec:
  selector:
    app: divide-service-py
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 5004
      targetPort: 5004
  type: NodePort

I've applied the Deployment and Service. The Pod is running but, when I try to access the Service through Minikube, I get connection refused errors.

There's lots going on here. One (relevant) debugging step you don't include is that, you should be able to (1) run your code locally (that will work) and then you should be able to (2) run the container locally. I think this won't work. This is because the Flask server binds (by default) to localhost (127.0.0.1) which result in your app not being publishable beyond the container. Instead you should have app.run(host="0.0.0.0",port=5004) so that you can access the app outside of the container. There may be other issues but please demonstrate these points and update your question.

This also looks to me like a duplicate of Deploying a minimal flask app in docker - server connection issues.  Can you docker run -p 5004:5004 the container, without Kubernetes, and connect to it?  Does adding the host="0.0.0.0" parameter that @DazWilkin suggests help?

thank you you save me love youuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu

now its work but when i try to run the service from another device with diffrent network it dosent work how i can do it ?
